# How to find the equations used in an N2 diagram?

Tags: unmanned-aerial-vehicle

I am currently pursuing my research internship whose aim is to validate the airframe design estimation by FastUAV, an optimization framework (written in OpenMDAO) specifically tailored to unmanned aircraft. I wonder how they have defined certain variables/parameters. Since the code has been written by someone else who has not left any accurate documentation, the only way to do that could be look at how they used those parameters in the computations. Hence, being new to UAV and N2 diagrams, my question is, how could I exploit this tool (N2 diagrams https://openmdao.org/newdocs/versions/latest/features/model_visualization/n2_basics/n2_basics.html) to look at the hidden equations?

Comment: Isn't the source code available? I think anyway that this question has more to do with coding than aviation being N2 diagrams related to the openmdao framework...

Comment: The OpenMDAO developers are active on StackExchange -- I don't immediately recall which forum they frequent, but you should be able to find them on here.

If you only have a printed N2 diagram, you won't be able to find out much other than the chosen breakdown into components (boxes) and the abstract inputs/outputs from one to another.  Without the code, you can't do what you want.